GA4 tag triggering
My GA4 tag is firing via the "DOM Ready" trigger (the user has not yet accepted or denied consent). Shall I fire it again, when the user makes a choice and the consent value is updated? Accepting consent emits an "update_consent" event. Shall I add this additional trigger to my GA4 tag, or is not necessary?

Open your GTM Preview, clear the consent cookie, load the page, see the DOM Ready fire and the CSP manager blocking the pageview tag. Allow consent. Do you see the pageview fired? No? Then your CSP Manager doesn't resend the events. Feel free to add the "update_consent" trigger to your pageview tag and it should fire after the consent is given.
